# python: PyYAML module not parsing to object

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

trying to get a YAML document to parse into python dictionary object that I can manipulate. I installed `pip install pyyaml`.

```
import yaml
yamlstring = "some: var \n another: 3"
type(yaml.load(yamlstring))
>> str
```

to my surprise it returns a string not a dictionary! what did I do wrong here?

Comment: To my surprise you get a `str` as output where I expect a scanner.Error.  At least Python 2.7 and 3.4  give that. What system are your running, which Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a data structure from a YAML string, it makes much more sense to use triple quoted strings, starting them with an escaped newline and ending them with a newline. Your example would then look like:

```
import yaml
yamlstring = """\
some: var
another: 3
"""
type(yaml.load(yamlstring))
```

That way it is far easier to spot the extra space before `another` as that would indent the YAML "structure".

If you want to do this nested in a function (and thus have leading whitespace) use `dedent` from the `textwrap` standard library to remove that extra leading whitespace.

Comment: well this is what the yaml string looks like `"options:  \n  preferences:\n    delay: 1\n    use_mouse : 1\n    properties: 0\n    async: 0"`

Comment: @user299709 that loads correctly (as a dict of 4 elements within a dict of one element). I am not sure what you want me to do with that example.

Answer (score 3):

Too much whitespace.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yamlstring = "some: var\nanother: 3"
>>> type(yaml.load(yamlstring))
dict
```

Comment: how to trim yaml white space?

Comment: @user299709 If it *needs* trimming, then you could use `str.strip()` somehow — but does it really?